# Automatically convert H2 to H₂ when typing in Indesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, grep

I have to regularly type the word H2 into documents for my job. I always forget to make the 2 subscript

I've been watching David Blatner's Indesign secrets and I figured I could use either, commonly misspelled word or to create a GREP Style.

I tried `\d.`, this works but, when I now type any number on its own it will be formatted to subscript.

Is there a way to only apply the formatting to the letters "H2" for it to read H₂?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apply the character style (subscript) to any number 2 preceded by `?<` an uppercase character `\u`

```
(?<=\u)2
```

or, apply the character style (subscript) to any number 2 preceded by `?<` an uppercase H

```
(?<=H)2
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to change this so that is doesn't change the 2 when its part of a specific word. "H2Van" Can't seem to figure it out. I've tried positive look behind and Match Character Set. I'm not sure what I can do. Any help?

Comment: This is another question, you can refer to this one when you make a new.

Comment: I have managed to figure it out. But it's not perfect will ask later. Will do the job just now.