# How to ignore word from global GREP style?

Tags: adobe-indesign, grep

I asked [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/122648/automatically-convert-h2-to-h%E2%82%82-when-typing-in-indesign) question to create a GREP style to make the 2 subscript when I typed H2.

I need the GREP to ignore the word H2Van.

I thought to amend the GREP to look for a space after the 2 as well as to look for a `H` or any uppercase letter before it. This does work, but if there is punctuation after the H2, then the GREP also ignores it.

How would I amend this GREP to ignore the word H2Van?

```
(?<=\u)2(?=[[:space:]])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just the 2 followed by a V, put the negative expression for the V after the 2  `(?!V)`

```
(?<=\u)2(?!V)
```